# Lazily coalesce Options in Scala

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, scala-option, coalescing

I have several ways of calculating a value, in decreasing preference.

```
firstWay()
second() + way()
orA(thirdWay())
```

Each of these returns an `Option`. I want to "coalesce" these and get an `Option` which the the value returned by the first `Some` of these, or `None` if all returned `None`.

Of course, if `firstWay()` returns a `Some`, I shouldn't calculate the rest.

What is the most idiomatic (or at least reasonably readable) way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
firstWay().orElse(second() + way()).orElse(orA(thirdWay()))
```

`orElse`'s argument is lazily evaluated.

See [the documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option).

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough ways that Karol's answer becomes unwieldy, or don't know in advance how many:

```
val options: Stream[Option[A]] = ...
// in the example: firstWay() #:: (second() + way()) #:: orA(thirdWay())

options.foldLeft[Option[A]](None)(_.orElse(_))
```